# How to create new object list from existing object list?

Tags: list, object, google-apps-script, mapping

I try this code, but only get a list of `undefined`.

```
    var categories = YouTube.VideoCategories.list(`id, snippet`, {regionCode : "US"});
    //good values
    
    var categories = YouTube.VideoCategories.list(`id, snippet`, {regionCode : "US"}).getItems().map(item =>  {id: item.id; title: item.snippet.title});
```

What is wrong with my syntax?

Comment: Syntax error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ';' line: 29 file: Code.gs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what your data structure is but from looking at the `map` I see you're using `new` which might be a typo?

I would fix this by doing this:

```js
var categories = YouTube
  .VideoCategories
  .list(`id, snippet`, {regionCode : "US"})
  .getItems()
  .map(item => ({id: item.id, title: item.snippet.title}));
```

Now your `map` returns the object in each iteration instead of running `new`

Comment: I tried without new and even with your code, but i get a syntax error: `Syntax error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ';' line: 29 file: Code.gs`

Comment: Sorry, fixed the syntax now

Comment: You are using javascript yes?

Comment: I don't know... probably... Better change that tag then

Comment: It's javascript, don't worry ;)